# With vagrant-berkshelf deprecated, will it be possible to drive builds from Vagrant, with Chef solely as a provisioner?

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra

I have had a number of issues recently with `vagrant-berkshelf` not syncing Chef cookbooks on an existing machine reliably.  And, basically, when doing research on workarounds, I see something like:

*vagrant-berkshelf is deprecated, use Test Kitchen instead*.

My use case is that I have `Vagrantfile`s, used to build VMs and DigitalOcean droplets, that are hand-written and only use Chef to provision the VMs.  I am most definitely approaching Chef as a user, not an author or tester of cookbooks.

So, I am in a case of `Vagrant -> Chef`, not `Chef -> Vagrant`.

When looking at [Kitche-Vagrant](https://docs.chef.io/plugin_kitchen_vagrant.html), I see that:

*The kitchen-vagrant driver for Kitchen generates a single Vagrantfile for each instance of Kitchen in a sandboxed directory.*.

My question is:  if my workflow relies on hand-written, complex, Vagrantfiles, can I continue to use Chef as a provisioner without having to rely on `vagrant-berkshelf`?

Some of the possible alternatives I see are:

- mangle Test Kitchen configuration to work with my exiting Vagrantfile.  I fear that this is not the intent of this tool and will not end well.
- use `chef.cookbooks_path` attribute in vagrant and let it take the place of vagrant-berkshelf.
- switch out provisioners and use say Vagrant->Ansible.

The Vagrantfile below is somewhat simplified, but the gist is that **the Vagrantfile is in charge and Chef is just used to provision**.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

#...grab some variables from my host environment...
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY = ENV['BUILD_DJANGO_SECRET_KEY']

Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|

  config.vm.define "myserver" do |config|
      config.vm.provider :digital_ocean do |provider, override|
        override.ssh.private_key_path = digoconf.private_key_path
        override.vm.box_url = "https://github.com/devopsgroup-io/vagrant-digitalocean/raw/master/box/digital_ocean.box"
        provider.token = digoconf.TOKEN
        ...
      end

      #had chef_client before, that worked too.
      config.vm.provision "chef_zero" do |chef|

        chef.log_level = "info"

        #I haven't tested these out
        #chef.cookbooks_path = ["../community/cookbooks","../.berkshelf/cookbooks"]

        env_for_chef = " DJANGO_SECRET_KEY='#{DJANGO_SECRET_KEY}'"
        chef.binary_env = env_for_chef

        chef.environment = "digitalocean"
        chef.add_recipe "base::install"
      end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't deprecated per se, but it does no longer have a maintainer and does highly recommend against its use. There is no replacement for the workflow you describe. Sorry. If you are interested in taking over as maintainer, I can put you in contact with the team.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  If it were Python, I might take you up on the offer and learn the Chef internals to help out, but I really struggle at Ruby.  And, not so great at Chef either, though I've learned a lot from using it and it's been very helpful to me so far.  One question though: do you know what `chef.cookbook_path` provides in vagrant?  It kinda seems like it should pull in cookbooks, even if I need to run `berks update` externally to keep them synced.  I'll keep this question open, in case someone else weighs in on that, but otherwise I'm leaning towards accepting your answer.

Comment: What you can do is run a `berks vendor` and then point the `chef.cookbook_path` at the resulting folder. That is basically what the plugin does internally, just using a lot more magic and some funky shared folders.

Comment: awesome.  I'll give that a try.